# Populating model in controller, getting nullreference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, nullreferenceexception

Hi I'm having a problem and I just can't seem to get it around. I want to populate part of my model then pass it to the view so the user can populate the rest and submit.

Here's the model

```
public class SelectModel
{
    public List<String> Scripts { get; set; }
    public string ScriptSelection { get; set; }
    public IFormFile InputFile { get; set; }

}
```

and here's where I'm trying to populate the list in the controller

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        SelectModel model = new SelectModel();

        model.Scripts.Add("Germany");

        return View(model);
    }
```

I'm getting null ref exception at   model.Scripts.Add("Germany");

I've populated a model from a view and passed it back to a controller before but I seem to be having issues initialising the model in the controller for my 1st view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling `Add` method on `NULL` . `model.Scripts` is NULL and hence you are getting the classic "**Object Reference not set to an instanc**e" error

Initialize it to an empty list before trying to add to it.

One way is to have a default constructor, which initialize your Scripts property to an empty list.

```
public class SelectModel
{
    public List<String> Scripts { get; set; }
    public string ScriptSelection { get; set; }
    public IFormFile InputFile { get; set; }

    public SelectModel()
    {
      this.Scripts =new List<string>();
    } 

}
```

Another option is to initialize it to an empty list when you create the object

```
var model = new SelectModel(){ Scripts =new List<string>() };
model.Scripts.Add("Germany");
```

You can also use the object/collection initializator syntax as well

```
var model = new SelectModel()
{
    Scripts = new List<string>()
    {
        "Germany", "USA"
    }
};
```

Comment: doh! thanks, seem to have just had a blind spot there for a few hours, seemed to have thought creating the model also created the things in it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the list. Something like

```
public class SelectModel
{
    public List<String> Scripts { get; set; } = new List<String>();
    public string ScriptSelection { get; set; }
    public IFormFile InputFile { get; set; }

}
```

or inside the controller action

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        SelectModel model = new SelectModel();
        //initialization of the list Before usage
        model.Scripts = new List<String>();
        model.Scripts.Add("Germany");

        return View(model);
    }
```